# Call a function from Included file?

Tags: php, function, include

I am making a PHP script that does some stuff for me, so I wont have to type out all the code over and over in my website documents.

Here is what I do:

```
// MyFunc.php
<?php
 function DoStuff()
 {
  $var = 'something'; 
  return $var;
 }
?>


// index.php
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
 Hi, I am currently doing <?php include "MyFunc.php"; echo DoStuff(); ?>, pretty cool, right?
</body>
</html>
```

However, it appears my function is not getting called. Am I doing anything wrong?

**Here is my full source**

```
//splashgen.php
<?php

$refid = $_GET['ref'];
$output = 'Company';

function GetSponsor()
{

    if($refid!='')
    {
        $dbhost = "localhost";
        $dbuser = "myuser";
        $dbpass = "mypass";

        $dbname = "mydb";

        $sqlselect = "SELECT * FROM egbusiness_members WHERE loginid='$refid';";

        $con = mysql_connect($dbhost,$dbuser,$dbpass) or die('Unable to connect to Database Server!');
        mysql_select_db($dbname) or die('Could Not Select Database!');

        $refid   = stripslashes($refid);
        $refid   = mysql_real_escape_string($refid);

        $result = mysql_query($sqlselect);

        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
           {
            $output = $row['name_f']." ".$row['name_l']." (".$refid.")";  
           } 
        mysql_close($con); 
    }   
    return $output;

}


?>

/////////

// index.php

...

<font style="font-size:19px" color="#0093C4" face="Calibri"><b>
This page was brought to you by: <?php $_GET['ref']; include "../splashgen.php"; echo GetSponsor(); ?> 
</b></font></div>
...
```

Comment: DoStuff(); as it is a function.

Comment: Aaah, damn! I'm too much of a Delphi'er.. :P

Comment: @Mythje7 Doesent work either..

Comment: @Jeff And it does not give any errors?

Comment: @Myth no, none at all however when adding Echo outside the function in the MyFile.php, it prints it

Comment: And what does it do if you put it all in 1 page instead of including it?

Comment: @Myth - That does not work either... Hmm..

Comment: @Myth - Wait, if I do it on a clean page, it does work (obviously I did not post the source to my project, but a minimal pseudo). I guess I should post my source then.

Comment: Oke that's really odd. You are using somekinda localhost obviously to run php on ... What if you replace : echo DoStuff(); by : echo "Hello"; ?

Comment: @Jeff Hm a break thru ... That would mean there is something going wrong on the include ... so you dubbel checked the names of the files i suppose ehm ... What about the answer i psoted/edited?

Comment: @Jeff What if you do print_r($output); ?

Comment: @Jeff No result at all? then it must be empty ... does $result have a value?

Comment: @Mythje - I tried changing the $output to $refid, which we know is set, and that did not work either

Comment: I even tried changing it to some static text, didnt work either..

Comment: <?php $_GET['ref']; There you do nothing with the value but calling it might that cause the problem?

Comment: @Mythje - Would that mess up the function? Because when I just Echo from the Include file, it works, but when calling a function, it doesent?

Comment: @Mythje - Did not fix it either

Comment: Probably would not but really it's the only flaw i saw ...
I would like to try some stuff but this pc has no software for hosting and writing php. When im home ill try some things if it isn't solved by then

Comment: @Mythje - Well, the problem is: Calling the function is not working.. :S

Comment: @Jeff Indeed if it can't even display static text there's nothing else that can be wrong.

Comment: @Myth - Adding the `return`at the top of the function did not work either..

Comment: @Myth - Fixed! Apparently, you can't use the global variables inside the function :P

Comment: @Jeff Hm ... that doesn't make sence lol. But if it fixes it :D and btw gratz ^^

Comment: @Mythje - Was a bastard to fix :P - Thanks! :)

Comment: @Jeff Most definitely was. No problem btw for what i did lol

Comment: @Mythje - It made no sense at all, I just dont get it :P

Comment: @Jeff I can't imagine that that is a normal behavior. Actually i can't imagine that i never used variables like that.

Comment: Well - could it be a bug in PHP itself?

Comment: Perhaps or a bug in the localhost maybe?

Comment: @Jeff lol yea but it shouldn't happen at all ;)

Comment: @Mythje - Exactly! Do you have Skype mate? :)

Comment: @Jeff Yep i do but i would prefer not to post it here(for security reseason or privacy or really not wanting every1 to know it) lol

Comment: @Jeff but if you know a way of doing it "secure" tell me :p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it was because I was using a variable not declared within the function, and apparently the function needs a parameter, like so:

```
Function DoStuff($var)
{
  if($var != '')
  {
   return 'I am currently '.$var;
  }
}

...

echo DoStuff('posting on Stack Overflow');
```

Answer (score 3):

```
<body>
 Hi, I am currently doing <?php include "MyFunc.php";  echo DoStuff(); ?>, pretty cool, right?
</body>
```

And make sure, your php files should start with `<?php`

Comment: where are splashgen.php and index.php stored (PATH)?

Comment: @Gaurav - public_html/splash2/index.php and public_html/splashgen.php

Comment: what does it give `var_dump($output)`?

Comment: @Gaurav - I replaced the `return` with your var_dump, and nothing came out

Comment: $output has nothing to display. thats why it is not shoiwng you anything. check database has the values you want.

Comment: @Gaurav - I tried doing `return $refid` which I know has something in it, but that does not work either?

Comment: try var_dump($row); in while loop

Answer (score 2):

You want `DoStuff()` (with parentheses) to actually call the function. Apart from that your code is fine.

Comment: It appears to say nothing at all - nope. Nothing.

Answer (score 1):

missing paranthesis?

```
echo DoStuff();
```

Answer (score 1):

you forgot to add parenthesis to function call.. change

```
    <body>
     Hi, I am currently doing <?php include "MyFunc.php"; echo DoStuff; ?>, 
pretty cool, right?
    </body>
```

to

```
    <body>
     Hi, I am currently doing <?php include "MyFunc.php"; 
echo DoStuff(); ?>, pretty cool, right?
    </body>
```

**UPDATE**

In repsonse to your update.. in your "full source" ..

Change

```
function GetSponsor() {
```

to

```
function GetSponsor($refid) {
```

and in HTML

Change

```
<font style="font-size:19px" color="#0093C4" face="Calibri"><b>
This page was brought to you by: <?php $_GET['ref']; 
include "../splashgen.php"; echo GetSponsor(); ?> 
    </b></font>
```

to something like

```
<font style="font-size:19px" color="#0093C4" face="Calibri"><b>
This page was brought to you by: 
<?php 
include "../splashgen.php"; 
$refid = $_GET['ref']; 
echo GetSponsor($refid); ?> 
</b></font>
```

I'll also advise you to sanitise this $refid so that you dont get sql injections...

Answer (score 0):

have you checked the location of the include is right? try adding "echo "hello world"; outside of the function in MyFunc.php, just to make sure it is being called.

Comment: Well the code seems spot on. Have you tried shifting the function into index.php and see if it runs from there?